# Как в коде на python написать запрос на сервер?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

пишу сервер с помощью fastapi, который должен принять запрос, обработать его каким-либо образом и создать свой запрос на сторонний сервер. Я уже понимаю, как описывать структуру принимаемого запроса с помощью fastapi, обрабатываю ее. Не могу понять, как в коде прописать отправку запроса на сторонний сервер (зная соответствующее API для этого сервера). Используется ли для этого каким-то боком fastapi? Нашел в интернете, что подобное в Python реализуется с помощью библиотеки requests. После установки всех компонентов fastapi в виртуальное окружение хотел еще установить библиотеку requests, оказалась она идет вместе с fastapi. Поэтому и спрашиваю, можно ли посылать в коде запросы с использованием фич fastapi или же следовать гайдам по библиотеке requests  и по известным шаблонам этой библиотеки писать запросы?

Comment: Ну скорее всего да, нужно через `requests` обращаться. `fastapi` насколько я понимаю только принимает запросы.

Comment: Может знаешь, почему во всех гайдах написано например писать requests.get(...), a у меня этот метод get () когда пишешь requests.  он не видит. Приходится писать requests.Request.get(). Может я какой-то модуль кроме requests из fastapi не импортировал или из самого requests нужно что-то еще импортировать?

Comment: А как вы делаете, `import request` или как-то по-другому?

Comment: Нет, я пишу from fastapi import FastAPI, requests

Comment: Ну так это видимо другой какой-то `requests`, внутренний от `fastapi`, надо по нему свою доку читать.

Comment: fastapi не предназначен для отправки запросов. Используйте просто requests (import requests).